# IIS 7 problem which does not occur under apache

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, iis, iis-7

I'm hosting a little site using a JavaScript to draw a simple graph. It involves one html index file, some css and some js files.

It has all been working perfectly on two different apache servers, but when I set up IIS 7 the ajax calls fail. I get no java debug errors in firefox that I can work with, or any kind of error message at all.

Without going into the code itself, does anyone have a similar experience with IIS? This is the first time I'm using IIS so I'm not quite sure what to expect to have trouble with. I'd love some input on this, if I have to delve into the code itself I'll make a new thread, I just thought I'd see if this could be a typical issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you already using Firebug to monitor the AJAX calls in the "Net" tab? What happens if you call the Ajaxy URLs directly? Are you sure all the script files are loaded properly? I'd look into the latter first.

Comment: Wow you are right, it does not find the ajax url. The file is there on the server, but it gives a 404 on request. I managed to fix that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are you already using Firebug to
>   monitor the AJAX calls in the "Net"
>   tab? What happens if you call the
>   Ajaxy URLs directly? Are you sure all
>   the script files are loaded properly?
>   I'd look into the latter first. –
>   Pekka Apr 8 at 9:15